# CSS Style Element if it does not contain another specific type of Element

Tags: css, image, anchor

My CSS includes the following:

```
#mainbody a[href ^='http']      {
        background:transparent url('/images/icons/external.svg') no-repeat top right;
        padding-right: 12px;
}
```

This places an "external" icon next to links that start with "http" (all internal site links are relative). Works perfectly except if I link an Image, it also get this icon.

For example: `<a href='http://example.com'><img src='whatever.jpg'/></a>` would also get the "external" icon next to the image. I can live with this if necessary, but would like to eliminate it.

This must be implement in CSS (no JS); must not require any special IDs, Classes, styling in the html for the image or anchor around the image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's case sensitive.  Just use all capped HTTP: for image links.

Comment: Well this is certainly simple; doesn't meet the requirements as the HTML has to be changed, but might end up being the simplest way to accomplish the intended result. Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

You can either:-

- Only use relative links for images
- link to a naked domain for images (e.g. http://domain.com) and fix
  the external link filter to www. rather than http.

No CSS required - you basically need to use a less common filter.

Comment: The problem I'm running across are Software/Company Buttons, those would always link to an external site... though may I could setup a redirector. I also try to avoid the "www" for all but [Wall of Fail](http://no-www.org/roster.php) domains. The filter is also intentionally short to catch https links too, though I could setup a separate link for that. Food for though; thanks!

Comment: It's a very tricky one. It's also possible to link to images from a sub-domain and set up an opposing filter based on it to remove the image.

Comment: The icon is on the image though, it's on the anchor (which only contains the image). So changing the image link would have no effect.

Comment: @ChrisS I mean literally countermanding the incorrectly applied CSS for spesifc instances